# How to include one page from another page in java?

Tags: java, linux, servlets, netbeans

I am new in java and i am developing web application in java.

I am trying to include one page to another page.But it gives path error in server side.

My another page is placed in user folder of root directory.

I am trying to include page like

```
<%@include file="../user_menu.jsp" %>
```

Its working on local host but not working in live linux server.

How can i fix this error?

Help me

Comment: Please give the folder structure information of page that want to include and where it need to include.

Comment: @pikrut:thanks for replay. I want to include header.jsp file in about_us.jsp,And my  about_us.jsp is in user folder.and header.jsp is outside the user folder.

Comment: Please check <%@include file="/header.jsp" %> in about_us.jsp

Comment: @pikrut:only / is give page not found error.

Comment: If it have any WWW url can you please give that?

Comment: @pikrut:www.site4demo.co.in

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33020/discussion-between-mansinh-and-pikrut)

Answer (score 1):

Use /path/to/your/file.jsp
Where / is your public_HTML dir

Comment: With public_HTML I mean your base tomcat jsp dir check your tomcat config

Comment: :actully i have two file about_us.jsp and header.jsp now about_us.jsp is in folder and header.jsp is out side the folder.so how can i include header.jsp in about_us.jsp page

Comment: :tomcat config chacke means? please elaborate